# Comparing and counting values in a table - Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently practicing on Spark using Scala language. I am using a data file with multiple headers but I am interested in comparing the values of only two columns. There are several thousand rows with reoccurring customers. These are '[customerID, busID, date_travel,Firstname, Lastname]'

I am interested in comparing both the customerID and busID of all the customers in the table and creating a column where it outlines the amount of instances two customers have been on the same bus. Each bus trip has a unique ID.

I have sucessfully loaded the data file into spark, created a dataframe and created a new value:
Dataframe example:

```
val exampleInputDF = Seq(("20185","344","01/06/2019","John","Smith"),("20186","344","01/06/2019","Jack","Sparrow"),("20187","344","01/06/2019","John","Wick")).toDF("customerID", "busID","date_travel","Firstname","Lastname")

+----------+-----+-----------+---------+--------+
|customerID|busID|date_travel|Firstname|Lastname|
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+--------+
|     20185|  344| 01/06/2019|     John|   Smith|
|     20186|  344| 01/06/2019|     Jack| Sparrow|
|     20187|  344| 01/06/2019|     John|    Wick|
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+--------+
```

```scala
val commonjourneys = spark.sql("SELECT customerID,busID, from data_table ORDER BY busID")
```

I am then thinking to use Window functions to create a new column but I am confused as to how I will be able to compare each of the values. Previously I would have `.filter($"customerID" = "BUS ID")` for a constant value but now the values are constantly changing. I think I could use an IF function but not sure where to start to implement that. Furthermore, to limit output, I am only looking to find instances where there are >2 bus journeys together.

My output would ideally have 3 columns - `[customerID - Passenger1, customerID - Passenger 2, number_of_journeys_together]`

Does anyone know how to approach this kind of problem and any functionality Scala/Spark has which may help complete this in the easiest way.

Comment: Give an example of the dataframe please

Comment: @SimbaPK updated in question.

Comment: What simba meant (I think), is can you provide sample data (and the code to generate it)? It is much easier for people to help you if they can quickly set up some sample data, execute what you tried and work from there ;-)

Comment: Yep Oli is right, thus i proposed a quick edit to your question munchen102

Comment: @SimbaPK thanks for the edit.I do not have much code other than that at the moment. I am puzzled as to the best way to approach the next part.

Comment: i'm working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution :

input :

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

    val ex = Seq(("20185","344","01/06/2019","John","Smith"),("20186","344","01/06/2019","Jack","Sparrow"),("20187","344","01/06/2019","John","Wick")).toDF("customerID", "busID","date_travel","Firstname","Lastname").select("customerID","busID","date_travel")

+----------+-----+-----------+
|customerID|busID|date_travel|
+----------+-----+-----------+
|     20185|  344| 01/06/2019|
|     20186|  344| 01/06/2019|
|     20187|  344| 01/06/2019|
+----------+-----+-----------+
```

Then i create a list of customer for each travel,
Then i filter this list to delete the customer ID associated with a UDF
Then i explode this list to have two columns with the customer ID and customerID2

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("busID","date_travel")

val d = ex.withColumn("listOfCustomerIDForEachBusForEachDate", collect_set("customerID").over(w))
    .withColumn("listOfCustomerWithoutCustomerID", filterCustomerListUDF(col("listOfCustomerIDForEachBusForEachDate"), col("customerID")))
    .drop("listOfCustomerIDForEachBusForEachDate")
    .withColumn("customerID2", explode(col("listOfCustomerWithoutCustomerID")))

d.show

+----------+-----+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------+
|customerID|busID|date_travel|listOfCustomerWithoutCustomerID|customerID2|
+----------+-----+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------+
|     20185|  344| 01/06/2019|                 [20187, 20186]|      20187|
|     20185|  344| 01/06/2019|                 [20187, 20186]|      20186|
|     20186|  344| 01/06/2019|                 [20187, 20185]|      20187|
|     20186|  344| 01/06/2019|                 [20187, 20185]|      20185|
|     20187|  344| 01/06/2019|                 [20185, 20186]|      20185|
|     20187|  344| 01/06/2019|                 [20185, 20186]|      20186|
+----------+-----+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------+


  def filterCustomerList(customerList : scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], customerID : String) : scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String] = {
    val outputList = customerList.filter(_ != customerID)
    outputList
  }

  val filterCustomerListUDF = udf(filterCustomerList _)
```

Then you can do a groupBy to get number_of_journeys_together

```
d.groupBy("customerID","customerID2").count()
  .withColumnRenamed("count","number_of_journeys_together").show

+----------+-----------+---------------------------+
|customerID|customerID2|number_of_journeys_together|
+----------+-----------+---------------------------+
|     20187|      20185|                          1|
|     20185|      20187|                          1|
|     20185|      20186|                          1|
|     20186|      20185|                          1|
|     20186|      20187|                          1|
|     20187|      20186|                          1|
+----------+-----------+---------------------------+
```

In this example, the result is always 1, but it's ok with this ex input dataframe

Comment: @munchen102 is it ok for you ?

Comment: Thank you . In the step of creating new columns, the action 'filterCustomerListUDF' - I seem to get an error saying value filterCustomerListUDF not found.

Comment: it's a custom udf, look at my code, it's below the d.show(), you have to create the udf separately in your code and call it in WithColumn

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know where is a good guide for me to learn more about defining my own functions in scala/spark, what parameters to use and how to structure them?